# Azure C# Function Binding dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I want to bind my event hub connection string dynamically. For instance, my environment can change per TEST, QA and PRODUCTION.

```
namespace CSFunction
{
    public static class MyCSFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("aFunction")]
        public static Task Run([EventHubTrigger("TEST-eventhub", Connection = "TEST-eventhub-ns_RootManageSharedAccessKey_EVENTHUB")]string myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("starting run...");
            log.Info($"message received: {myEventHubMessage}");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the event hub and connection string dynamically? EventHubTrigger only allows a constant string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mikhail is correct. You can find detail answer in Azure Doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---app-settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Connection` property should be set to a name of Application setting which contains the connection string, not the connection string itself. E.g.

```
Connection = "EventHubConnectionAppSetting"
```

Thus, the connection string can be changed dynamically in App settings.

To do the same for Event Hub name, put the property between `%` symbols:

```
EventHubTrigger("%myeventhub%")
```

and then add a setting with corresponding name (`myeventhub` in my example) and value `TEST-eventhub` or `QA-eventhub` etc.

Comment: Thats great help